# Magento 2 add custom validation rule for two dynamic fields

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

In admin product edit page I added dynamic fields. Now I want to validate the filed based on the value of another field.

For example, I want to make `Value` Required/Optional based on the value of `Unit`

[image]